# Meaning of light-blue cross on map-canavas

Tags: qgis-3

What is the meaning of this **light blue cross sign** on the map canvas of QGIS?
I upgraded from 3.34 to 3.36 and now I see this cross sign, when opening a new blank project and also on some, but not all old projects

[image]