Blue cross in middle of QGIS map canvas - how to remove?
QGIS has started putting a blue cross in the middle of the map canvas. I've seen earlier posts where this was found to be caused by a plug-in, and disappeared after the plug-in was updated. However, I don't have the particular plug-in mentioned. And I uninstalled everything but the core plug-ins, which you apparently cannot update. It's still there. Even tried upgrading to the latest version (Maidenhead) from Prizren. Still there.
How do I get rid of this cross? It's really annoying.

Same issue as this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478960/meaning-of-light-blue-cross-on-map-canavas
